# Make promo/coupon codes on retail site only good when site is accessed using my referrer code?

Tags: e-commerce

I am building a site where my partner e-commerce sites can promote their sales on my site.  For example, a retailer would adverstise a promotion on my site and a link on my site ("Enter Sale") would take them to the retailer's site using a referrer code.

Once there, users would be able to use special coupon/promo codes at checkout to get their discount.

My question is this: can my partner-retailers easily set things up on their end so that these special promo/coupon codes will only work when used after getting to the site with my referrer code? (i.e. so codes won't work when users go straight to the retailer's regular url)

Comment: Didn't you ask almost the exact same question some minutes ago?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing a "sale" on e-commerce website by clicking a link on my website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569776/accessing-a-sale-on-e-commerce-website-by-clicking-a-link-on-my-website)

Comment: Impatient? 46 minutes not long enough to get an answer?

Comment: Well I didn't think it was exactly the same question.  I apologize.  I thought the other answers indicated I could easily have my partners set up referrer codes.  Can they do that so the promo/coupon codes I give them will only work when the get to the retail site through my site?

Comment: Then they would have to see that the http header field refer is your domain.

Comment: Thanks Kai. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

Just let them check the http header, too.

See this here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer